# Java if numbers in list are over x

Tags: java

I am using
`if(Collections.frequency(pattern, l) > 15)`
to check if there is a long that reoccurs 15 times in a list. What I also need to do is something like
`if(Collections.frequency(pattern, >500) > 15)`
so it will check how many times a number over 500 occurs in the list also, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I don't think you read my question at all.

Comment: Can you write your own function? Or do you have have to use Java collections?

Comment: `if (pattern.stream().filter(x -> x > 500).count() > 15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if(pattern.stream().filter(p-> p > 500).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() > 15)
```

Comment: Why would you write `.collect(Collectors.toList()).size()` instead of `.count()`?  That wastes memory and cycles.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this is not an original answer. I just put @tammy and @LouisWasserman's 
 answer to make it easy to understand for whoever hasn't used Java 1.8 before.**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FrequencyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<Integer>(){{
            add(1);
            add(501);
            add(599);
            add(499);
            add(11);
            add(11);
            add(12);    
        }};

        int count = intList.stream().filter(p-> p > 500).count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specifically ask for a Java 8 answer, this should work in most Java versions, but is easily modifiable to use lambda expressions.

I think what you really want to have the ability to "swap out", or have multiple versions of a function that can be used without rewriting code.  That is separating the criteria from the count.  In this case, you will need to pass an in instance of an interface that implements a method which determines if the criteria has been met.  In the case below, I called it `IMyComparator` which is passed into my own static `frequency` method.

This way in my own "Collection" class, I can have a `frequency` that operates like `Collections.frequency`.

```
public class MyCollection {

    private interface IMyComparator {
        public int isCriteriaMet(Integer source, Integer target);
    }

    private class MyComparator implements IMyComparator 
    {
        public int isCriteriaMet(Integer source, Integer target)
        {
            if ((source == null) || (target == null)) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (source.intValue() > target.intValue()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }

    private Collection<Integer> numbers;
    private IMyComparator imc;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCollection test = new MyCollection();
        int result = MyCollection.frequency(test.numbers, 500, test.imc);
        System.out.println("Frequency of numbers > 500: " + result);

    }



    public MyCollection() {
        numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 100, 200, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000));
        imc = new MyComparator();

    }

    public static int frequency(Collection<Integer> c, Object target, IMyComparator imc) {

        int count = 0;

        for (Integer element: c) {
            count += imc.isCriteriaMet(element, 500);
        }

        return count;

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the `frequency()` function looks for an exact match for an object so you couldn't. Can you not loop through the collection the old fashioned way and compare each element and add a counter?

```
for (iterable_type iterable_element : collection) {
   if (iterable_element > 500) counter++;
}
```